# Is lodash find supposed to behave differently in the browser than node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, find, lodash

Chrome = 58.0.3029.110;
Node = 6.9.2;
Lodash = 4.17.4
Used lodash-cli to build.

In node:

```
_.find([{n:1},{n:2}], {n:3});
> []
```

In browser

```
_.find([{n:1},{n:2}], {n:3});
> undefined
```

I don't think that this is suppose to happen... Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Just FYI, the documentation matches the behavior you're seeing in the browser.

Comment: Are you sure it's really returning an empty array, and it's not just an artifact of node's console display?

Comment: I'm unable to repro with Node 8.0 and Lodash 4.17.4 from npm.

Answer (score 0):

Well thanks to Barmar, it's just a console thing. I rebuilt my node and it's doing what is expected.